# Se todos os campos forem válidos enviar notificação e enviar o email se não forem mostra erros

Tags: php, javascript

*Verificação de um formulário de contacto com mensagens de sucesso e de erros*

**Atenção as correcções que fiz ao longo do tempo!**

**CÓDIGO PHP**

```
 if (isset($_POST['contact'])) {

  $nomecomp = test_input($_POST["nomecomp"]);
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nomecomp)) {
  $nomecompErr = "Apenas letras e espaços permitidos"; 
}

  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
 if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
 $emailErr = "Email inválido"; 
  }
 $assunto = test_input($_POST["assunto"]);
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$assunto)) {
 $assuntoErr = "Apenas letras e espaços permitidos com máximo de 25 
 carácteres";
 }

  $mensagem = test_input($_POST["mensagem"]);
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$mensagem)) {
  $mensagemErr = "Apenas letras e espaços permitidos";  
 }
else
 {

 echo '<script>',
 'jsFunction();',
 '</script>';
 $mailto = "testesphp123@hotmail.com";
  $headers = "From:". $email;
  $txt = "Recebes-tes um email de ". $nomecomp . ".\n\n".$mensagem;
  mail($mailto, $assunto,$txt,$headers);
}

  }
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
   }

?>
```

**FORM**

```
      <form method="post" role="form" class="contactForm" action="">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left">
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="errormessage">* <?php echo $nomecompErr;?> *</span>
          <input type="text" name="nomecomp" class="form-control form" 
        id="name" placeholder="Nome Completo"  REQUIRED />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="red">* <?php echo $emailErr;?>*</span>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" 
    placeholder="Email"REQUIRED />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                         <span class="error">* <?php echo $assuntoErr;?>* 
   </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="assunto" 
   id="subject" placeholder="Assunto" maxlength="25" REQUIRED/>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right">
        <div class="form-group">
              <span class="error">* <?php echo $mensagemErr;?>*</span>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="mensagem" rows="5"  
     placeholder="Mensagem" REQUIRED></textarea>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!-- Button -->
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="contact" class="form 
   contact-form-button light-form-button oswald light fundoazul">Enviar 
    email</button>
      </div>
     </form>
```

**JS**

```
     function jsFunction() {
         $.bootstrapGrowl("A sua mensagem foi enviada com  sucesso!", { type: 'success' });
       }, 1000;

    </script>
```

**Biblioteca**

```
     <script src="js/jquery.bootstrap-growl.min.js" type="text/javascript"> 
    </script>
```

**Resolução com PHP e JS**

**Novo JavaScript**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {



 var aux= "<?php echo($_SESSION['varphp']); ?>";

if(aux == 1) {               
                $.bootstrapGrowl("A sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso", { 
type: 'success' }); 
     }
    });   

     </script>
```

**PHP**

Declarar a variável de sessão

```
    $_SESSION["varphp"]=0;
```

*E trocar isto:*

```
   echo '<script>',
   'jsFunction();',
   '</script>';
```

*Por isto:*

```
     $_SESSION["varphp"]=1;
```

Comment: email esta sendo enviado corretamente?

Comment: Sim está já alojei no meu dominio!

Comment: Estou tentando resolver meu problema de outra maneira agora!

Comment: Resposta editada!  e com a explicação de  como mandar o utilizador, após submissão, para a parte da página onde está  o form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A sua `Resolução com PHP e JS` ainda não me parece adequada, pois envia email mesmo com validação errada.

**Front-end**

1. Basta entrar no console e alterar seu formulário, como por exemplo retirar o REQUIRED, ou aumentar o maxlength que o mail será enviado. Portanto é importante também a validação no `Back-end`
2. Se preencheres o campo `assunto/mensagem` somente com espaços o mail será enviado.

**Back-end**

> Sessões no PHP não são "inseguras" porém a maneira como você programa pode causar uma dor de cabeça

### Solução proposta

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ifightcrime.github.io/bootstrap-growl/jquery.bootstrap-growl.min.js"></script>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['contact'])) {

$situacao="Enviar";

  $nomecomp = test_input($_POST["nomecomp"]);
  if(strlen($nomecomp)<=2){
     $nomecompErr ="Preencha o nome com no mínimo 3 caracteres.";
     $situacao="naoEnviar";
     $nomecomp="";
  }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nomecomp)) {
     $nomecompErr = "Apenas letras e espaços permitidos"; 
     $situacao="naoEnviar";
  }

  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     $emailErr = "Email inválido"; 
     $situacao="naoEnviar";
  }

  $assunto = test_input($_POST["assunto"]);
  if ( (strlen($assunto)<=2) || (strlen($assunto)>25) ){
     $assuntoErr = "Preencha o campo assunto com no mínimo 3 caracteres e no máximo 25 caracteres";
     $situacao="naoEnviar";
  }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$assunto)) {
     $assuntoErr = "Apenas letras e espaços permitidos com máximo de 25 carácteres";
     $situacao="naoEnviar";
  }

  $mensagem = test_input($_POST["mensagem"]);
  if(strlen($mensagem)<=10){
     $mensagemErr = "Preencha o campo mensagem com no mínimo 10 caracteres.";  
     $situacao="naoEnviar";
  }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$mensagem)) {
     $mensagemErr = "Apenas letras e espaços permitidos";  
     $situacao="naoEnviar";
  }

  //se tudo está ok envia email e apresenta mensagem de sucesso
  if ($situacao=="Enviar"){
      //mensagem na tela
      echo "<script>
      $(function() {
         $.bootstrapGrowl(\"A sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso\", { type: 'success' });
     });
     </script>";

     //envio de email
     $mailto = "testesphp123@hotmail.com";
     $headers = "From:". $email;
     $txt = "Recebes-tes um email de ". $nomecomp . ".\n\n".$mensagem;
     mail($mailto, $assunto,$txt,$headers);

     //com o envio do email corretamente, anulamos as variaveis para limpar os campos
     $nomecomp = "";
     $email = "";
     $assunto = "";
     $mensagem = "";

  } 

}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

?>


<form method="post" role="form" class="contactForm" action="">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left">

       <div class="form-group">
          <span class="errormessage">* <?php echo $nomecompErr;?> *</span>
          <input type="text" name="nomecomp" class="form-control form" 
          id="name" placeholder="Nome Completo" value="<?php echo $nomecomp;?>"  REQUIRED />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <span class="red">* <?php echo $emailErr;?>*</span>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" 
          placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" REQUIRED />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <span class="error">* <?php echo $assuntoErr;?>* </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="assunto" 
          id="subject" placeholder="Assunto" maxlength="25" value="<?php echo $assunto;?>" REQUIRED/>
      </div>

   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right">
      <div class="form-group">
         <span class="error">* <?php echo $mensagemErr;?>*</span>
         <textarea class="form-control" name="mensagem" rows="5"  
         placeholder="Mensagem" REQUIRED><?php echo $mensagem;?></textarea>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!-- Button -->
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="contact" class="form 
        contact-form-button light-form-button oswald light fundoazul">Enviar 
        email</button>
   </div>

</form>
```

> Após a submissão direcionar para parte especifica da pagina.

- Em um URL, um simbolo jogo da velha (`#`) direciona um navegador a um local específico em uma página ou site.

  1 - Coloque um `id` no formulário, exemplo `id="form"`

  2 - No action do formulario `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."#form"; ?>`

*Exemplo*

```
<form method="post" role="form" class="contactForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."#form"; ?>" id="form">
```